# How can I get the MessageAttributes of an sns message in an ios app?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push, amazon-ses

I've connected an SNS endpoint to an ios app. When I publish to the sns endpoint:

```
                anSNS.publish(
                    TargetArn=userLUT['mobrien'],
                    Message=aMessage,
                    MessageAttributes={
                        'one': {'DataType': 'String', 'StringValue': aOne},
                        'two': {'DataType': 'Number', 'StringValue': aTwo}
                    })
```

I receive the message in the launchOptions from this contructor:

```
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

as the .alert string.

I do not receive the MessageAttributes in the launchOptions dictionary. How do I get the message attributes as well?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. You need to switch the message type to "json" and then you pass in the json structure into the Message attribute for the "APNS" (or "APNS_SANDBOX") structure.

```
anAPNS = '{{ "aps": {{ "alert": "{}", "one": "{}", "two": "{}" }} }}'.format(aMessage, 'one', 'two')
anSNS.publish(
                    TargetArn=arnGoesHere,
                    MessageStructure='json',
                    Message=json.dumps({
                        'default': aMessage,
                        'APNS_SANDBOX': anAPNS,
                        'APNS': anAPNS
                    }))
```

The MessageAttributes are not passed to the final apns message.